# drush perm-grant gives "The drush command 'perm-grant' could not be found"

Tags: 7, users, drush

I am using `drush -u 15 perm-grant --roles="site administrator"` but the command returns:

> The drush command 'perm-grant' could not be found.

any ideas about that? according [this](http://drupal.org/node/802272) documentation the `drush perm-grant` is an available command. or maybe is some limitation of the user used to run drush?

the drush version is 5.4

thanks.

Comment: Do you have the Permissions API module installed and enabled?  That perm-grant isn't provided by drush itself, the module does.

Comment: note also that Drush 8.x-6.x (latest Drush dev release) has user role and permissions commands built-in.

Comment: thanks both for the indications, thanks MPD, permissions_api seems that is a module for Drupal 6 [http://drupal.org/project/permissions_api](http://drupal.org/project/permissions_api), so this command does not work in drupal 7. thanks greg , I will ask if is possible some change in the drush version.

Answer (score 0):

according @MDP, [Permissions API](http://drupal.org/project/permissions_api) module is required for this, and according its module page is only for Drupal 6, so this command is not available in drupal 7. @greg_1_anderson user recommends to use Drush 8.x-6.x to get this feature working built-in